# Incorrect values returned by sp::over function?

Tags: r, r-sp

I'm extracting elevation data of a route from a Digital Elevation Model using

```
my.elev <- over(new.points, mygrid)
```

- new.points is a SpatialPoints object, with the coordinates (long/lat) of about 7000 points transformed in the CRS of mygrid
- mygrid is a SpatialGridDataFrame with more than 8 millions elements 
  ([more info in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014134/how-to-extract-specific-values-from-a-dem-digital-elevation-model/27035003))

Having several NA values in my.elev, I debugged my code and I found that almost all the points in new.points repeated more than one time (in my route few segments are crossed two times): 
- the first occurrence has the corresponding my.elev value correct 
- the second one has a NA value (or sometimes, a quite different value)

I can easily solve the problem eliminating the duplicated values in new.points, but I wonder why the over function doesn't return the same value for the same point.

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example?

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik, I made several attempts, but I've no errors with small data.

Comment: wow, I didn't know the edit of a comment has only 5 minutes!

Comment: My previous comment was:
Hi @RomanLuštrik, I made several attempts, but I've no errors with small datasets... 
So, it seems the problem is connected with the specificity of my data.

Comment: In case the problem is still existent, please send me the data reproducing this off-list.